# Restrict IR sensor field of view

Tags: sensor, infrared, proximity-sensor, tracking

I'm trying to develop a device that can detect or "watch" an infrared beacon that is freely moving side-to-side anywhere within a 180° field of view (-90° to +90°, with center/forward at 0°); i.e. the sensor should see the beacon if it is directly to the left (-90°), to the right (+90°), or anywhere inbetween, but *not* if the beacon is anywhere behind the sensor.

I've glued a little IR sensor ([TSOP38238](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/tsop382.pdf)) on top of a micro servo ([Tower Pro SG92R](http://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/sg92r-7/)), and I have these wired up to a [Circuit Playground Express](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-circuit-playground-express/overview) with [CRICKIT](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-crickit-creative-robotic-interactive-construction-kit). I'm programming on the board via Arduino, and the software seems to be working great -- the servo will continuously sweep the full field of view, and if the specific IR signal I'm transmitting (38kHz, NEC IR protocol with 32-bit payload data) is received by the sensor, the servo's current position/angle is logged immediately.

However, my problem is restricting the IR sensor's vision. For example, if the servo with IR sensor are facing left (-90°), and the IR signal is being transmitted from front and center (0°), the IR sensor detects that signal and thus determines that the source of the signal came from the left (-90°). This example is real and practical, but the problem is in fact far worse; the sensor is detecting IR transmissions from all 360° -- **there is no direction the servo and IR sensor can face that it will *not* detect the source IR signal being transmitted!**

The only thing I know to do is to fabricate blinders to surround the IR sensor. If I can somehow block (reflect, absorb, whatever) any IR signal to which the sensor does not have a direct line-of-sight, then it should help prevent these undesirable signals. Or even if I can't *block* the signal, perhaps it's possible to *corrupt* it to cause a change in frequency or payload data.

I've constructed some blinders using craft sticks and super glue, with several layers of aluminum foil (like you use in the kitchen) taped to the outside. [I added the aluminum because of this SE thread I found](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43389/what-common-materials-can-effectively-block-infrared-radiation). But still, the IR signals seem to pass right through.

So what other techniques or materials are possible here to restrict IR signals to line-of-sight?

---

The blinders I constructed look like the following. The wooden side faces the inside (faces the IR sensor), aluminum side faces outward (faces the world):

[image: Outside of panel 1, inside of panel 2]

And the following is how the blinders are mounted onto the servo, with the IR sensor inbetween. The intent is to blind signals coming from the sides, but still allow the signals to reach the sensor if coming from different heights:

[image: Parallel panels as mounted on servo]

Comment: With an estimated 80dB of AGC gain the Rx reflection  threshold can easily span a  100:1 range. If your backside range is only 2:1 distance of the front side you can see the problem of detection by error rate.  Even if you reduced the Tx current to 1% of the existing current you will still not get decent proximity detection without false positives or true negatives.

Comment: Maybe I should have pointed out I'm brand new to electronics, as that comment went clear over my head starting with the first sentence

Comment: AGC is automatic gain control like that used in radios.  80 dB means a 10,000:1 dynamic range in signal levels, If you can define the actual Geometry in your question, it may be possible to solve this.

Comment: @ardnew if you look at my answer you will see that AGC is linked (as wall as COTS) to wikipedia pages explaining what they mean.  Beyond that, I don't think you need to know much more then what you want are the type of detectors that count people (the type I linked to).  Not the type of detectors used for remote controlling your TV set (the type you have).

Comment: @ardnew, I should add, once you get the correct detectors, you can likely either use much smaller blinders or simply do away with them.  Also, since you are new to stack exchange, you should eventually pick a correct answer so as to let the community know what worked for you.  The point being you are setting things up so that the next person asking this question will already have the correct answer.

Comment: `IR signals seem to pass right through` .... not through aluminium foil ..... you are detecting a reflection

Comment: @jsotola i've also used the smooth plastic body of a mechanical pencil, wrapping aluminum foil around it completely 7-8x, then inserted the IR sensor inside this aluminum-enclosed tube, and it still somehow picks up IR signal. if it is reflection, the only regions not enclosed with aluminum are the tiny gaps where the sensor leads enter the tube.. but if I enclose my transmitter in the same aluminum foil, nothing is detected. so, somehow, I think you must be right

Comment: i am talking about reflection from walls or from objects in the room

Answer (score 1):

These Vishay detectors are molded from IR-transparent resin and IR of modest intensity can penetrate the back side and internal reflection in the part can give an unexpected positive detection.  They are not designed for mono-directional IR because they are typically folded back against the PCB where a copper fill on the pcb blocks any back light and a two-shot molding process of IR-transparent lens + IR-opaque body would just add cost.

A very effective and easy solution is to wrap a piece of black electrical tape around the perimeter (center the small part on the wide tape and leave the excess on the front as a shroud and then fold the excess to cover the back. Add another small piece to fill in any opening on the back side.  Then test your rig again to see if you get 360° detection.  Be aware that IR light is very good at reflecting off of lighter colored walls and ceilings.  I often play that game with the grand kids where I don't point the remote at the TV and it still works. They try but can't quite get the angles right so grandpa is magical.

Answer (score 0):

Almost with out exception [COTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_off-the-shelf) IR remote control receivers contain an [AGC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_gain_control) circuit.  The [Vishay](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/tsop382.pdf) part used contains such a circuit (see block diagram at the bottom of page 1).  This feature allows for dependable detection regardless if the IR transmitter signal is received directly or if received bounced off a wall.

What is needed in this application is a beam interruption detector.  These are less common but [Vishay makes several including this one.](https://www.vishay.com/docs/82458/tssp40.pdf)  Note that there is no AGC circuit in the block diagram.  When the signal drops below a certain threshold the output goes inactive.

Comment: Although it has no AGC, it probably uses a precision limiter that handles the also huge irradiance max:min ratio of 50k : 0.4 mW/m² or a 100 dB range

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem before using a PIC to transmit unique TDM spaced codes to each 5mm IR LED and then recessed IRDA Rx's going to a PIC.

**First, you must define the room geometry, distances involved, range of motion, reflection materials and distance, then how you want to detect orientation by some truth table and desired Tx locations.** Like North-East-West-South or front-back?

IRDA and IRDA2  Rx-TX optos are designed for speed but short range but can be made to work for a small room at a suitable pulse duration.   There is no need to use the actual IRDA protocol as I invented my own protocol with a unique Tx code.

Since optical path loss is a point source with power spread by the square of radius distance, the signal reduces to 10% or -20 dB for a change in distance of any units from 1 to 10x the range.  (The same applies to RF aka Friis Loss) for line-of-site.

Answer (score 0):

I would try enclosing the IR sensor in a metal enclosure (painted black internally), and add a lens. Basically make a camera with only 1 pixel. A lens with focus in only 1 axis would be ideal.

There are many types of IR fresnel lenses available for motion detector applications. One of them should work.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any material that is opaque to visible light is also opaque to infrared.  The exception would be special plastic or glass that appears black but is transparent to infrared.

So a flat sheet of opaque material immediately behind the detector should block everything.

Since you can't see infrared, it's easy to forget that it reflects off walls and other surfaces like any other light.  Is it possible that your detector is picking up reflected light?